# reshaping the dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas, melt

I have this dataset:

| Account | lookup | FY11USD | FY12USD | FY11local | FY12local |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | CA | 1000 | 5000 | 800 | 4800 |
| Sales | JP | 5000 | 6500 | 10 | 15 |

Trying to arrive to get the data in this format: (below example has 2 years of data but no. of years can vary)

| Account | lookup | Year | USD | Local |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | CA | FY11 | 1000 | 800 |
| Sales | CA | FY12 | 5000 | 4800 |
| Sales | JP | FY11 | 5000 | 10 |
| Sales | JP | FY12 | 6500 | 15 |

I tried using the below script, but it doesn't segregate USD and local for the same year. How should I go about that?

```
df.melt(id_vars=["Account", "lookup"], 
    var_name="Year", 
    value_name="Value")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One efficient option is to transform to long form with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), using the `.value` placeholder ---> the `.value` determines which parts of the columns remain as headers:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(
     index = ['Account', 'lookup'], 
     names_to = ('Year', '.value'), 
     names_pattern = r"(FY\d+)(.+)")

  Account lookup  Year   USD  local
0   Sales     CA  FY11  1000    800
1   Sales     JP  FY11  5000     10
2   Sales     CA  FY12  5000   4800
3   Sales     JP  FY12  6500     15
```

Another option is to use stack:

```py
temp = df.set_index(['Account', 'lookup'])
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split('(FY\d+)', expand = True).droplevel(0)
temp.columns.names = ['Year', None]
temp.stack('Year').reset_index()

  Account lookup  Year   USD  local
0   Sales     CA  FY11  1000    800
1   Sales     CA  FY12  5000   4800
2   Sales     JP  FY11  5000     10
3   Sales     JP  FY12  6500     15
```

You can also pull it off with `pd.wide_to_long` after reshaping the columns:

```py
index = ['Account', 'lookup']
temp = df.set_index(index)
temp.columns = (temp
                .columns
                .str.split('(FY\d+)')
                .str[::-1]
                .str.join('')
               )
(pd.wide_to_long(
      temp.reset_index(), 
      stubnames = ['USD', 'local'], 
      i = index, 
      j = 'Year', 
      suffix = '.+')
.reset_index()
)

  Account lookup  Year   USD  local
0   Sales     CA  FY11  1000    800
1   Sales     CA  FY12  5000   4800
2   Sales     JP  FY11  5000     10
3   Sales     JP  FY12  6500     15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can piece it together like so:

```
dfn = (pd.concat( 
[df[["Account", "lookup", 'FY11USD','FY12USD']].melt(id_vars=["Account", "lookup"], var_name="Year", value_name="USD"),
df[["Account", "lookup", 'FY11local','FY12local']].melt(id_vars=["Account", "lookup"], var_name="Year", value_name="Local")[['Local']]], axis=1 ))
dfn['Year'] = dfn['Year'].str[:4]
```

Output

```
  Account lookup  Year   USD  Local
0   Sales     CA  FY11  1000    800
1   Sales     JP  FY11  5000     10
2   Sales     CA  FY12  5000   4800
3   Sales     JP  FY12  6500     15
```